# Adding 'space' in C# textbox

Tags: c#, textbox

1. Hi guys, so I need to add a 'space' between each character in my displayed text box.
2. I am giving the user a masked word like this `He__o` for him to guess and I want to convert this to `H e _ _ o`
3. I am using the following code to randomly replace characters with `'_'`

   ```
       char[] partialWord = word.ToCharArray();

       int numberOfCharsToHide = word.Length / 2;          //divide word length by 2 to get chars to hide 
       Random randomNumberGenerator = new Random();        //generate rand number
       HashSet<int> maskedIndices = new HashSet<int>();    //This is to make sure that I select unique indices to hide. Hashset helps in achieving this
       for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCharsToHide; i++)       //counter until it reaches words to hide
       {
           int rIndex = randomNumberGenerator.Next(0, word.Length);       //init rindex
           while (!maskedIndices.Add(rIndex))
           {
               rIndex = randomNumberGenerator.Next(0, word.Length); //This is to make sure that I select unique indices to hide. Hashset helps in achieving this
           }
           partialWord[rIndex] = '_';                      //replace with _
       }
       return new string(partialWord);
   ```
4. I have tried : `partialWord[rIndex] = '_ ';`however this brings the error  "Too many characters in literal"
5. I have tried : `partialWord[rIndex] = "_ ";` however this returns the error " Cannot convert type string to char.

Any idea how I can proceed to achieve a space between each character?

Thanks

Comment: Not a duplicate (as far as I know) but with a bit of googling you would have found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189293/add-spaces-between-the-characters-of-a-string-in-java of which you can almost directly copy the loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should do as you ask. I think the code is pretty self explanatory., but feel free to ask if anything is unclear as to the why or how of the code.

```
// char[] partialWord  is used from question code
char[] result = new char[(partialWord.Length * 2) - 1];
for(int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
{
    result[i] = i % 2 == 0 ? partialWord[i / 2] : ' ';
}
return new string(result);
```

Comment: can you please comment on the line `result[i] = i % 2 == 0 ? partialWord[i / 2] : ' ';` . I am not fully understanding the meaning of `result[i] = i % 2 == 0 ?`

Comment: when I implemented this, this code is altering my original code in a way I am not managing to figure and all of my words are being left with only one unknown letter, whereas before the unknown letters or '_' was `int numberOfCharsToHide = word.Length / 2; `

Comment: i % 2 == 0 ? partialWord[i / 2] : ' '; is a shorthand if. it is equivalent to if(i%2 == 0) {result[i] = partialWord[i/2];}else {result[i] = ' ';}

Comment: where did you put the code? it should replace your return new string(partialWord);

Comment: I am inserting the for loop under `partialWord[rIndex] = '_';`  and I think that is the problem.

Comment: it needs to be outside the masking loop, so that is indeed likely to be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Since the resulting string is longer than the original string, you can't use only one char array because its length is constant.

Here's a solution with `StringBuilder`:

```
var builder = new StringBuilder(word);
for (int i = 0 ; i < word.Length ; i++) {
    builder.Insert(i * 2, " ");
}
return builder.ToString().TrimStart(' '); // TrimStart is called here to remove the leading whitespace. If you want to keep it, delete the call.
```

Comment: you can use a char array because you "know" the length of the final string.

Comment: @prof1990 Yes this can be done with two char arrays, but not one. That's why I said "can't use _a_ char array". I just like to use StringBuilder more personally.

Comment: to each is own, but might I suggest you clarify your answer to saying it cant be done using just one char array?

Comment: Thanks for your contribution @Sweeper.