# Add a space between every Chinese character

Tags: java, android

I have a string in Java which could look like this:

> 我今天說了：Good morning 的一句英語

I want it to become this:

> 我 今 天 說 了 ：Good morning 的 一 句 英 語

Basically a space is added between every Chinese characters or symbols **while other languages are unaffected**.

I think determining the Unicode block for CJK characters could be a good way to do it, as Japanese and Korean are not expected to be used.

There are many questions on adding a space to every character, regardless of language, which does not achieve my aim.

Comment: `There are many questions on adding a space to every character, regardless of language, which does not achieve my aim.` Why not? What have you tried and what went wrong with your attempt?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add spaces between the characters of a string in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189293/add-spaces-between-the-characters-of-a-string-in-java)

Comment: I have tried solutions similar to what Nikolas suggested as possible duplicate, which adds spaces to every single character blindly. I want a space to be added between every Chinese(or CJK) characters only, while leaving English/Latin characters untouched.

Comment: @FeiKuan Have you Googled `java determine if character is chinese`? Use virtually any of the resources immediately available from that search and pair it with the solution you found already to add spaces between all characters.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357938/detect-chinese-character-in-java (dont forget to upvote)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a RegExp and the replaceAll method of the String class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String test = "我今天說了：Good morning 的一句英語";

  System.out.println(test.replaceAll("(?<=\\p{sc=Han})", " "));
}
```

Cheers,
A.