# how to give space after every character of a string in "jasper report"

Tags: jasper-reports

How to give space after every character of a string in jasper reports. I need this functionality to print date according to cheque format. I am new to jasper. Please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

**Adding blank to every character**

unfortunately Jasperreports doesn't support letter spacing ([source](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/there-way-change-letter-spacing))

However you can always use java in text fields to tranform the string and add a blank character after each character.

For example in case you have a field `myString` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189293/add-spaces-between-the-characters-of-a-string-in-java) for java part):

```
<textFieldExpression>
    <![CDATA[$F{myString}.replace("", " ").trim()]]>
</textFieldExpression>
```

**More specifically on dates**

Java also provides nice feature to format a date. You might consider this as you specified you were working with dates.

An example of date formatting :

```
<variable name="dateFormatter" class="java.text.SimpleDateFormat">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
<textFieldExpression>
    <![CDATA[$V{dateFormatter}.format($F{myDate})]]>
</textFieldExpression>
```

See full documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

replaceAll() works fine in jasper reports only if RegularExpression is added in the imports.
 value="com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xpath.regex.RegularExpression"/>

$P{mystring}.replaceAll("", " ").trim()