# Having trouble filling an array of binary numbers from an integer

Tags: java, arrays, methods, computer-science

This is the question we were assigned  :

Nine coins are placed in a 3x3 matrix with some face up and some face down. You can represent the state of the coins using a 3x3 matrix with values 0 (heads) and 1 (tails). Here are some examples:

0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0
0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1

Each state can also be represented using a binary number. For example, the preceding matrices correspond to the numbers:

000010000 101001100 110100001

There are a total of 512 possibilities, so you can use decimal numbers 0, 1, 2, 3,...,511 to represent all the states of the matrix.

Write a program that prompts the user to enter a number between 0 and 511 and displays the corresponding matrix with the characters H and T.

I want the method toBinary() to fill the array binaryNumbers. I realized that this does not fill in 0s to the left. I have to think that through but is that the only thing that is the problem?

```
//https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-program-for-decimal-to-binary-conversion/ 
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class HeadsAndTails {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
    int num = input.nextInt(); 
    int[] binaryNumbers = toBinary(num);

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {

    printArr(binaryNumbers); 
    System.out.print(binaryNumbers[1]); 
}
}

public static int[] toBinary(int inputtedNumber) { 

    int[] binaryNum = new int[9]; 
    int i = 0; 

    while (inputtedNumber > 0) { 

        binaryNum[i] = inputtedNumber % 2; 
        inputtedNumber = inputtedNumber/2; 
        inputtedNumber++; 

    } return binaryNum; 

} 
public static void printArr(int[] arr) { 

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {

        if (arr[i] == 0) { 

            System.out.print("H "); 

        } else { 

            System.out.print("T "); 

        }

        if (arr[i+1] % 3 == 0) {

            System.out.println(); 

        } System.out.print(arr[i]);

    } 

}
}
```

Comment: Inside the `while` loop of the `toBinary` function `i` is not changed.

Comment: I didn't run your code, but seems you print the identical result 9 times. `for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) { printArr(binaryNumbers); ... }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you are incrementing the wrong variable in your `while` loop:

```
while (inputtedNumber > 0) { 

    binaryNum[i] = inputtedNumber % 2; 
    inputtedNumber = inputtedNumber/2; 
    i++; // NOT inputtedNumber

} return binaryNum;
```

Also note, a `new int[9]` is probably already initialized to **0**, but if not, you could just *loop 9 times*, rather than until the `inputtedNumber` is **0**:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) { 
    binaryNum[i] = inputtedNumber % 2; 
    inputtedNumber = inputtedNumber/2; 
} 
return binaryNum;
```

Finally, I think your array might be backwards when you're done, so you may need to reverse it or output it in reverse order

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a homework assignment so you should stick with your current approach. However, sometimes it can be fun to see what can be achieved using the built in features of Java.

The `Integer` class has a method `toBinaryString` that's a good starting point:

```
    int n = 23;
    String s1 = Integer.toBinaryString(n);      
    System.out.println(s1);
```

Output: `10111`

But as we can see, this omits leading `0s`. We can get these back by making sure our number has a significant digit in the 10th place, using a little bit-twiddling:

```
    String s2 = Integer.toBinaryString(1<<9 | n);       
    System.out.println(s2);
```

Output: `1000010111`

But now we have a leading `1` that we don't want. We'll strip this off using `String.substring`, and while we're at it we'll use `String.replace` to replace `0` with `H` and `1` with `T`:

```
    String s3 = Integer.toBinaryString(1<<9 | n).substring(1).replace('0','H').replace('1','T');
    System.out.println(s3);
```

Output: `HHHHTHTTT`

Now we can print this string in matrix form, again using `substring` to extract each line and `replaceAll` to insert the desired spaces:

```
    for(int i=0; i<9; i+=3)
        System.out.println(s3.substring(i, i+3).replaceAll("", " ").trim());
```

Output:

```
H H H
H T H
T T T
```

If we're up for a bit of regex wizardry (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297347/splitting-a-string-at-every-n-th-character) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189293/add-spaces-between-the-characters-of-a-string-in-java)) we can do even better:

```
    for(String sl : s3.split("(?<=\\G.{3})"))
        System.out.println(sl.replaceAll(".(?=.)", "$0 "));
```

Putting it all together we get:

```
    int n = 23;
    String s3 = Integer.toBinaryString(1<<9 | n).substring(1).replace('0','H').replace('1','T');
    for(String s : s3.split("(?<=\\G.{3})"))
        System.out.println(s.replaceAll(".(?=.)", "$0 "));
```

Comment: Interesting... can you explain the Integer.toBinaryString(1<<9 | n); syntax? Knowing about the .replace() would have been really useful.